# xCode iOS Dev - Parse Issue : Expected Identifier?

Tags: ios, parsing, identifier

Check this out & let me know what you guys think is wrong.
Thank you very much. :)

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as text rather than as a screenshot.

Comment: if([[Reachability (id)] currentReachabilityStatus] == NotReachable)
    { 
  UIAlertView *av = [[[UIAlertView alloc] 
       initWithTitle:@"Sorry" 
       message:@"You are not connected to the internet. Please Try again"
       delegate:nil 
       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
       otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
  [av setDelegate:self];
  [av show];
 }

Comment: How do I make my code appear any clearer? I am new to this site & desperately need help.

Comment: From outside I have a feeling you are missing 'CFNetwork.framework' and 'System.Configuration' framework.

Comment: The "Reachability.h" is imported at the start of the file.

Comment: @PsychedelicFuzz: please read the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help); such content belongs in the question rather than comments.

Comment: yes sir. you got it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you have written type (id) & not written any identifier for this (id), thats why it is giving error.compiler always except identifier after the data type.

it should be only

```
[reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if([[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] currentReachabilityStatus] == NotReachable)
```

OR, In clear way

```
- (BOOL)connected
{
    Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
    return !(networkStatus == NotReachable);
}
```

Instead of

```
if([[Rechability (id)]  currentRechabilityStatus] == NotRechable)
```

Put

```
if(![self connected])
```